# cakePHP popen() with 2 commands using windows

Tags: php, cakephp, cron

I want to write a cron manager that works with windows and (I think) I need 2 commands in sequenz to get there.

Basically a cron starts my script that runs through a foreach.
Each loop goes to my function, which should start a console script in the background (so that the main script won't have to wait for each script to finish)

```
protected function runWindows() {
    $command = 'cd ' . APP . // first I want to redirect to the correct folder
        ' && .\Console\cake importer.import'; // second I want to address my script
    pclose(popen('start /B ' . $command . ' 2>&1 &' , "r"));
}
```

Either command works on its own, so my issue is to find the correct way to send 2 command with popen if possible.

note: I think I need to redirect before starting the actual script. In Unix context, this && should work.